# Easiest way to insert image into docx file using PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, .doc

I am trying to set up an export button on a website that will export some information from a database and put it into a .doc file. I'm currently doing this with:

```
$filename = "File.doc"; 

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

echo "<html><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\"><body><img src='the_img.png' width='250px'><br><br><b style='font-size: 40px;'><u><center>Header</center></u></b><br><br><ol>";

$fileData = "SELECT `Songs` FROM `table`;";
$info = $con->query($fileData);
while ($the_row = $info->fetch_assoc()) {
    $content = $the_row["column"];
}

$arr = explode("|", $content);

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    echo "<li>" . $arr[$i] . "</li>";
}

echo "</ol></body></html>";

mysqli_close($con);

exit;
```

When it exports the .doc file it successfully opens in Microsoft Word, however the image appears to be broken until you enter edit mode. Once you're in edit mode the image has no specific size set. Any suggestions?

Comment: HTML is not Word format. You want to use a lib like https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord to create a "real" word document.

Comment: Any way to get that without using composer?

Comment: Download from github. But using composer is highly recommended as always.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line I think

```
echo "<html><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows- 
1252\"><body><img src='the_img.png' width='250px'><br><br><b style='font-size: 40px;'> 
<u><center>Header</center></u></b><br><br><ol>";
```

You have to change the name of the image to be without space and add "style" before "width" like this

```
<img src="theimg.png" style="width:250px"/>
```